# HorizontalAlignment problem in stackpanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

HorizontalAlignment setting of textblock does not work when I add 2 textblock in stackpanel

what is the reason of this ?

Xaml:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Background="#312a28">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Name="current_page" Text="ÖZET" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock Name="next_page" Text="KASA" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: `does not work` - [explain](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: I don't know why, but stackoverflow doesn't add, I guess I can't handle it.
Adding below

Comment: try setting the StackPanel's HorizontalAlignment to Stretch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal" ignores `HorizontalAlignment` of children elements.

if you need layout like

```
=======================
| (ÖZET)       (KASA) |
=======================
```

then try Grid:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Background="#312a28">
   <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
      <TextBlock Name="current_page" Text="ÖZET" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
      <TextBlock Name="next_page" Text="KASA" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

Comment: @EmircanAydın, nice! If the answer helped you to solve the issue, please mark it as accepted (there is a check mark on the left side of answer)

Comment: an you reach me ? I have a question but I can not bring the topic because I'm a new member

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to the right border of "StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal". StackPanel is filled with elements one by one according to their size. Use grid instead or set margin of the element.

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Background="#312a28">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Name="current_page" Text="ÖZET" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBlock Name="next_page" Text="KASA" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Border>
```